# As I read (foreach php) this array stdClass

Tags: stdclass

I have the following code which gives me a query generated , what I need it is to walk the array ( php foreach ) to query the data.
I tried to do with the classic foreach (php) but I foreach throws an error.
Thanks in advance...

```
Array (

[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [_new] => 
        [_attributes] => Array
            (
                [id] => 36
                [nombre] => Diana
                [estado] => 1
            )

        [_related] => Array
            (
            )

        [_c] => 
        [_pk] => 36
        [_alias] => t
        [_errors] => Array
            (
            )

        [_validators] => 
        [_scenario] => update
        [_e] => 
        [_m] => 
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [_new] => 
        [_attributes] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [geoCode] => MAX
            )

        [_related] => Array
            (
            )

        [_c] => 
        [_pk] => 1
        [_alias] => t
        [_errors] => Array
            (
            )

        [_validators] => 
        [_scenario] => update
        [_e] => 
        [_m] => 
    ))
```

As I walk or convert to be read as ?

```
<?php foreach ($response as $value) {echo $value->nombre;} ?>
```

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$nombre

Comment: The solution is $value->_attributes['nombre']